# List Selector for multicolor list in Android

Tags: java, android-layout, android

I am having a list in my android application. The list items are custom objects and depending on the custom object property, list item color will be decided.

Now the problem is, when I select any item for such list, List selector is not displayed.

How can I fix this issue? To set list item color, I am using following method in adapter.

`convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY`)

Is this the right way to set color? if not what else I can use.

Thanks in advance.

Swapnil Dalal.

Comment: Do you want to use different different color or use the same color for list selector ?

Comment: put you adapter code here... you got ans quickly

Comment: Have my answer solved your problem, if yes, please admit it.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by two ways:

`1`.Write a selector for the itemview which set the background to the transparent in the **pressed state**, then set the selector as the backgound of the itemview.

```
<item android:state_enabled="true"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@color/gray" />

<item android:state_enabled="true" 
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
```

`2`.Remove the listselector, just write a selector for the itemview with the color you wanted by the different state and set it as the background of the itemview.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your getView method code so that we can help you better. One common mistake we do is that we don't always create new view for each item in the list view for loading different layout list Items.

For example common approach for identical itemed list:

```
if(view == null)
{
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fb_list_row, parent, false);
}
```

While for different object listview items you need to remove if statement like this;

```
vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fb_list_row, parent, false);
```

and then do the changing for each list item..

Hope this will help. Else put some more code.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this question,

I created to different xml files for different objects in the application.
So in the getView of adapter, depending on condition we can load either one of the xml.

Example:

```
`if(true) {
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.firstxml);
 }
 else {
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.secondxml);
 }`
```

In these xmls, we can specify colors as required.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@color/transperent"/>    
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/listview_selector" />
</selector>
```

Thanks,

Swapnil Dalal.